# How to override nav-pills dropdown styles in Bootstrap 4?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to changes colors of menu links modifying my CSS. As menu a chose `nav-pills`. Here is my code.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
      <div class="container">
        <ul class="mr-auto nav nav-pills">
          <li class="nav-item dropdown">
            <a class="nav-link" href="#" data-toggle="dropdown">My dropdown</a>
            <div class="dropdown-menu">
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">l1</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">l2</a>
              <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">l3</a>
            </div>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
.nav-pills > li > a {
  background-color: #888;
  color: white;
}

.nav-pills > li > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li > a:focus,
.nav-pills > li > a:active {
  background-color: #123 !important;
  color: #085;
}
```

The menu pill looks fine until I click it. On hover it behaves well too. But when I click it, the text color becomes white. And when I hold my cursor on a link in the dropdown menu the pill gets standard blue instead of staying dark-blue. How could I fix it?

I am working with Bootstrap 4.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the CSS :active selector.

https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_active.asp

```
.nav-pills > li > a:hover,
.nav-pills > li > a:focus,
.nav-pills > li > a:active {
  background-color: #123 !important;
  color: #085;
}
```

In your specific case, you can fix issue by adding:

```
.show > .nav-link {
  color: #085 !important;
}

.nav-pills > li.show > a:focus,
.nav-pills > li.show > a:not(:focus) {
  background-color: #123 !important;
  color: #085;
}

.dropdown-item:active,
.nav-link:active {
  background-color: #123 !important;
}
```

Here is the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/smulvihill/s9d76pbu/18/).

Comment: Updated the answer with a fiddle.

Comment: Thanks, it works for the text color. But the background is still standard blue when I am holding a link in the dropdown menu.

Comment: Updated answer and fiddle to get colors working as your described.